# ActiveMQ statistics logging

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm using activeMQ configured with spring jms, and I want to log and save statistics on the queues. I added

```
<plugins>
    <statisticsBrokerPlugin/>
</plugins>
```

to my activemq.xml.

How do I log the  information and how do I see this. can I use the `http://localhost:8161/hawtio` to do this?

I want to do this for future statistics

Comment: Have you looked at the ActiveMQ documentation?  There is an example here: https://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html. If you have specific problems update your question with details of what you've tried.

Comment: what statistics do you want to see? ActiveMQ comes with JMX that has plenty of statistics, you can see from JMX console or hawtio.